# filtering data - how to filter unwanted data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, express, filter

I have a JSON  file with data that I need to filter.

the json is this example structure :

```
[{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{B:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{B:"data", C:"flightData"},
{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{B:"data", D:"FlightData"}]
```

I am using group by method

```
 function groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
        const map = new Map();
        list.forEach((item) => {
            const key = keyGetter(item);
            const collection = map.get(key);
            if (!collection) {
                map.set(key, [item]);
            } else {
                collection.push(item);
            }
        });
        return map;
    }
```

First I group by either A or B  into Arrays

`A is [[C],[D]]` and `B is[[C],[D]]`

However if the data does not have either C or D I need to delete the group as the data is not needed.

```
 for (let value of s1) {

           // A or B
          const routeGrouped = groupBy(PriceArrayFinal, route =>
                   route.FinalArrival);



            for (let origin of s3) {

          // C or D 
         const originGrouped = groupBy(routeGrouped.get(value), route =>

                     route.FirstDepartCityName);
```

Is it possible to delete the full group eg A:  `[ [C], [] ]` if either C or D is not there. If there is an empty array , I need to delete the A or B group?

EDIT : Expected Output : All groups of A or B have both C and D

```
[{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{B:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"}] 

 [ [ [Array], [Array] ], [ [Array], [Array] ] ,[ [Array], [Array] ], [ [Array], [Array] ] ]
```

Comment: can you please add the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the objects which have value for `C` && `D`, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```js
let input=[{A:"data",C:"flightData",D:"FlightData"},{B:"data",C:"flightData",D:"FlightData"},{A:"data",C:"flightData",D:"FlightData"},{B:"data",C:"flightData"},{A:"data",C:"flightData",D:"FlightData"},{B:"data",D:"FlightData"}];

let output = input.filter(({ C, D }) => C && D);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Array [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
const arr = [{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{B:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{B:"data", C:"flightData"},
{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{B:"data", D:"FlightData"}];

const result = arr.filter(a => { 
 return (a.hasOwnProperty('A') || a.hasOwnProperty('B') && a.hasOwnProperty('C') && a.hasOwnProperty('D'));
});


console.log(result);
/* Expected Output:
[{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{B:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"},
{A:"data", C:"flightData", D:"FlightData"}] 
*/
```